# Spring security tag lib in joinfaces using sec:authentication

Tags: jsf, spring-security, joinfaces

It is not possible to use the spring security tag `<sec:authentication>` in joinfaces.

It will result in :

```
Tag Library supports namespace: http://www.springframework.org/security/tags, but no tag was defined for name: authentication
```

Is this not implemented by joinfaces? How can i register the spring implementation?

`<sec: authorize>` is working fine.

i have included the spring security taglib.

Comment: Maybe an old or newer spring security taglib or the wrong namespace prefix?

Comment: comment still the same! The error already indicates you included a taglib where the prefix refers to, otherwise you'd not have gotten this error. Investigate what is IN this taglib/jar file... (not a joinfaces issue btw, more spring-security related)